# Word for "to whine mockingly"?

Tags: word-request

I'm pretty sure there's a word for that. Example sentence:

> Oh, pink shoes. Couldn't you pick something girlier?" his brother __.

Comment: "Mocked"? "Grumbled"? I'm assuming the pink shoes are not for himself? I'm having a tough time imagining a "whine" that is "mocking," so I'm not one hundred percent sure what the best fit would be for you.

Comment: As an aside, there *is* a [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/), so perhaps they would be able to help you as well?

Comment: whinge http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whinge might be appropriate, although it does not have the mocking element

Comment: "Mock" seems to be what you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bleat mockingly works. Bleat alone might work with the mocking part evident in context.

"Oh, Pink shoes, couldn't you pick something girlier?" bleated his brother.

Or

"Oh, Pink shoes, couldn't you pick something girlier?" his brother bleated mockingly.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleat

Bleat :  to talk complainingly or with a whine